# Cannot seem to set char* correctly

Tags: c

I just wrote a program:

```
int main() {
    char* test = malloc(5);
    *test = "testc";
    printf("Test=%c",test[4]);
}
```

Which I would expect to give me "c" but it gives me nothing at best, and a segmentation fault at worst. What am I possibly doing wrong? Do I need to create a separate variable and `strncpy()` it's in? I also tried:

```
int main() {
    char* test = malloc(5);
    char* test2 = "test"
    strncpy(test,test2,4);
}
```

Which behaves correctly but seems sorta long. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: This shouldn't even have compiled, or at least it should have given you a warning.  Don't ignore warnings, *fix* them.  Especially before posting a question.

Comment: You used `strncpy` incorrectly. It would be good to avoid using that function, it's error-prone and you need to read its documentation carefully to avoid introducing bugs in your code. There's always a better way than strncpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,

```
 *test = "testc";
```

is very wrong. You are trying to put a pointer into a `char` variable. Enable warnings in your compiler and it will scream.

What you should do is, **either**

- Don't malloc, and assign the string literal to the pointer directly.
- Use `malloc()` and then `strcpy()` the string literal into the memory pointed by the pointer.
- Don't `malloc()`, don't `strcpy()`, use `strdup()` and store the result in the pointer.

The catch(es) is (are)

- First case, the string literal will be non-modifiable.
- Later two cases, you need to `free()` the allocated memory.
- The last way is a bit *non-standard*, strictly speaking.

Comment: Aaah,  I see, thank you that helps very much.

Answer (score 1):

In this program

```
int main() {
    char* test = malloc(5);
    *test = "testc";
    printf("Test=%c",test[4]);
}
```

you allocated memory

```
    char* test = malloc(5);
```

As result the pointer `test` points to the allocated memory.

When you tried to reasign the prointer

```
*test = "testc";
```

However you used a wrong syntax.

Expression `*test` has type `char` and in this statement you tried to assign the first character of the memory pointed to by `test` with the address of the string literal.

But if you wrote the expression correctly as

```
test = "testc";
```

there was a memory leak because the address of the allocated memory is lost in this case and the memory can not be free.

And moreover if the pointer must to point to a string then you need to allocate 6 characters to provide the terminating zero also would be stored in the allocated memory.

What you need is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char *test = malloc( 6 );

    strcpy( test, "testc" );
    printf( "Test=%c\n",test[4] );

    free( test );
}
```

or you could just write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char *test = "testc";

    printf( "Test=%c\n",test[4] );
}
```